# Copy Specific columns(all at once) in Datatable using C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two DataTables. The columns of the first table are

> A B C D E

The Columns of the second table are

> B C F D E G

I want to copy the data of all the columns from the first Table whose name exists in the second Table.

My Table is quite big so I don't want to assign it Column by Column

I am doing something like that (only snippet)

```
foreach (string colname in sourceColumnNames)
    {
       if (!targetColumnNames.Contains(colname)) continue;
       // There are other steps as well
       tRow[colname] = sRow[colname];
    }
```

But it is not very optimal.

I am trying to do it using ItemArray. So I can copy the whole array(only the columns I need) at once. 
My idea is to match columns name between the source and target table and store it in the dictionary and make an item array from that dictionary.

Is there any other optimal way of copying the specfic columns between 2 data tables with out going through each column

Comment: I guess the question is why would you want to copy? I guess you have access to the `dataSource` ?

Comment: Do you need the 2nd table?...what about copying the first table and renaming and dropping columns?

Comment: Some calculation is done on the source table and the result is stored in the target table

Comment: Both Tables are needed. it is necessary to have the result in target table

Comment: Target table have different columns but only the same columns data is copied to the target table

Comment: So you have a second table with some columns not present in the first one. This second table has rows or is empty when you start this work? If there are some rows how do you map the values coming from the first table to the rows already present? Do you have some kind of relationship between data in these two tables?

Comment: The second table(Target) is empty. It only has the columns but no data. Yes, both have different columns. I want only the common columns i.e. to copy data from first source table to target

Comment: The target table has no direct relation with the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you are checking common columns for every row. Since these columns are the same for every row you only need to do this once. Here is my idea of solving it:

First step is to create a mapping of columns from table 1 to table 2:

```
//Create a mapping
List<Tuple<int, int>> columnMappings = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
for (int dt1ColumnIndex = 0; dt1ColumnIndex < dt1.Columns.Count; dt1ColumnIndex++)
{
    string columnName = dt1.Columns[dt1ColumnIndex].ColumnName;
    if (dt2.Columns.Contains(columnName) == true)
    {
        int dt2ColumnIndex = dt2.Columns.IndexOf(columnName);
        columnMappings.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(dt1ColumnIndex, dt2ColumnIndex));
    }
}
```

Now you are able to iterate all rows of the first table creating new rows to table 2:

```
//Add all rows from table 1 to table two based on the mapping
foreach (DataRow dt1Row in dt1.Rows)
{
    DataRow dt2Row = dt2.NewRow();
    foreach (Tuple<int, int> columnMapping in columnMappings)
    {
        dt2Row[columnMapping.Item2] = dt1Row[columnMapping.Item1];
    }
    dt2.Rows.Add(dt2Row);
}
```

Comment: Its an improvement from my method. But still, the program will copy each matching column one by one. Is there a way to copy all at once like ItemArray.

Comment: Since `DataRow`s are managed objects I don't think there is a way to copy it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataTable.Load` method. It copies the source rows to destination table and you don't have to worry about columns mapping. An example how to do that:

```
dataTable2.Load(dataTable1.CreateDataReader());
```

For more information about `DataTable.Load` look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is a good practice to explain the answer and post the relevant code. It is discouraged to just post the link.